# Error while compiling GMT(generic mapping tool on centos7) with GDAL

Tags: linux, centos, libraries, shared-library, gdal

I am having the following error while compiling GMT with GDAL and I am unable to figure out the root cause of it.
GDAL has been compiled from the source (following [this link](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnUnix)). Dependencies too has been compiled from the source.

```
[ 70%] Linking C executable gmt
/opt/gdal3/lib/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `inflateValidate'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/gmt] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/gmt.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you set $LD_LIBRARY_PATH before compiling?

Comment: Yes, I already did.